# Can I connect with Redshfit from Angular for reporting?

Tags: angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I need to connect Angular with redshift for historical reporting. Can it be achieved, what are the prerequisites ?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible in theory using the [Redshift Data API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/data-api.html), but you should consider whether you truly want your client machine to be writing and executing SQL commands directly to Redshift.

To allow this the following are true:

- The client machine will send the SQL to be executed, a malicious actor could modify this so permissions would be important.
- You would need to generate IAM credentials via a service like Cognito to directly interact with the API.

It would be more appropriate to create an API that can directly communicate with Redshift offering protection on the SQL that can be executed.

This could use API Gateway and Lambda to keep it simple, with your frontend calling this instead of directly writing the SQL.

More information is available in the [Announcing Data API for Amazon Redshift](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/09/announcing-data-api-for-amazon-redshift/) post.